# Prevent Parent of Recycler From Collapse When Scrolling

Tags: android, kotlin, layout, android-recyclerview, scroll

I have a problem where the parent of a recyclerview collapses when I scroll within the recycler view. I would like for the "parent" to not collapse when the recyclerview is scrolled. I tried to use `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` but this didn't work. Any assistance would be appreciated.

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/green">
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomSheetLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_sheet_background_drawable"
        android:elevation="25dp"
        app:behavior_hideable="false"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="65dp"
        app:layout_behavior=".CustomSheetBehavior">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/back_white"
            android:id="@+id/ll_search">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:id="@+id/et_search"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_search2"
                android:drawableStart="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
                android:drawablePadding="6dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ll_search"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_bottom_sheet_recycler_view">
        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to use `recyclerView.stopNestedScroll()` in

```
    recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(OnTouchListener { v, event ->
})
```